# Mysql Select yesterday values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DATETIME field named "data" into table tomada. I want get all fields of yesterday. when I echo $num_rows, the value is 0. Where is the problem?

```
$sql ="SELECT amperagem FROM tomada WHERE data = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";// 
mysql_select_db('localiza');

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($retval);
echo $num_rows;
```

Comment: Note that several years ago someone decided to deprecate PHP's mysql_ API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`WHERE data = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

to

```
WHERE date(data) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Your `data` is `datetime` and it will also include `H:i:s` and doing `Y-m-d` with datetime will return nothing so you need to do the conversion to date while doing the compare.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT amperagem FROM tomada WHERE DATA = SUBDATE(NOW(), 1);
```